# Adding a parameter by default to all API calls in Swagger UI

Tags: jersey, swagger-ui

I want to use Swagger UI with Jersey REST APIs. I want to add an extra parameter to all APIs in Swagger UI but don't want to change the APIs itself(don't want to add corresponding @QueryParam in APIs).

How can I achieve this?

Swagger version i'm using: v2.1.4